How do I print a file's contents with four extra spaces at the beginning of each line?
I have a file called test.txt with the following contents:
blah
foo
bar

I'm attempting to write a script using the command prompt in Windows that will find the path of the file named test.txt and then print its contents with four extra leading spaces at the beginning of each line so that the output can be copied and pasted into a Reddit post with code block formatting (Reddit does not format triple-backticks as code blocks), like this:
    blah
    foo
    bar

So let's say in my case the full path of the file is C:\Users\Test User\test.txt, although I cannot assume the file will always be in the same directory - it depends on where I've installed my games - which is why I'm using dir to locate the file first.
The following command seems to find all instances of the file as expected.
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /s/b test.txt') do @set myfile=%i

After which point, issuing echo %myfile% prints the file path as I expect: C:\Users\Test User\test.txt.
Now to print the contents of the file with four extra spaces at the beginning of each line, here's what I've tried so far:
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in (%myfile%) do @echo     %i`

Which results in the following:
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Test.

I think the space in the file path is causing problems, so I tried wrapping %myfile% in double quotation marks, like this:
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ("%myfile%") do @echo     %i`

But that just prints the file path, which isn't what I want, either:
    C:\Users\Test User\test.txt

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Your second example should be: for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in ("%myfile%") do @echo     %i, but it will ignore any empty lines. Have you tried it like this: For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "$" "%myfile%" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo    %G

@Compo for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in ("%myfile%") do @echo     %i just prints an empty line. For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "$" "%myfile%" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo    %G prints     ■b.

If you are getting that character at the first line then you are probably parsing a unicode file with a bom. It may even contain non printable characters. That isn't my fault that you did not provide that information. Try this instead: For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "" 0^<"%myfile%" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo    %G.

@Compo the suggestion in your second comment does it - thank you so much! Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

You shouldn't need to define a variable either, just do it in one go, For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('Dir "test.txt" /A:-D /B /S 2^>NUL') Do @For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "" 0^<"%G" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo    %H. BTW, parsing a doublequoted iile in a for loop has been answered before, as has those with a bom. For those reasons there should be no answer entered below.

@Compo the suggestion in your third comment results in 2> was unexpected at this time, but I think I can work with the suggestion in your earlier comment. Thanks for your help.

I was proof reading it and fixed that already.

it's much simpler in powershell: ls -s test.txt |% { gc $_ |% { "    " + $_ } }. Full version: Get-ChildItem -Recurse test.txt | Foreach-Object { Get-Content $_ | Foreach-Object { "    " + $_ } }
